# dynamic routing with vue router in vue js with strapi headless CMS - router link and a href tags throwing errors

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I'm building out a strapi site with vue js.

In strapi, I have a custom collection type called "webinars" - the endpoint to hit that looks like this:

`const response = await axios.get('http://localhost:1337/webinars')`

The above returns a JSON object.

To hit individual webinars, each one has a unique identifier, starting at 1. to hit the individual webinar JSON data that looks something like this:

`const response = await axios.get('http://localhost:1337/webinars/1')`

Which would return a particular webinar.

I need 2 views, one is all of the webinars, and specific ones.

So to start, please see my router below:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import VueRouter from 'vue-router'
import Home from '../views/Home.vue'
import Webinars from '../views/Webinars.vue'

Vue.use(VueRouter)

const routes = [
  {
    path: '/',
    name: 'Home',
    component: Home
  },
  {
    path: '/about',
    name: 'About',
    // route level code-splitting
    // this generates a separate chunk (about.[hash].js) for this route
    // which is lazy-loaded when the route is visited.
    component: () => import(/* webpackChunkName: "about" */ '../views/About.vue')
  },
  {
    path: '/webinars',
    name: 'Webinars',
    component: Webinars
  },
  {
    path: '/webinars/:id',
    name: 'Webinars',
    component: WebinarSingle
  }
]

const router = new VueRouter({
  mode: 'history',
  base: process.env.BASE_URL,
  routes
})

export default router
```

Now, my view that returns all the webinars looks like this:

```
<template>
    <div>
      <h1>{{ header }}</h1>
      <div v-if="error" class="webinar-error">
        <h1>{{ error }}</h1>
      </div>
      <div v-else>
        <div class="webinar-card" v-for="webinar in webinars" :key="webinar.id">
            <h3>{{ webinar.webinar_title }}</h3>
            <p>{{ webinar.webinar_description }}</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
import axios from 'axios';

export default {
  name: 'Webinars',
  data () {
    return {
      webinars: [],
      error: null
    }
  },
  async mounted () {
    try {
      const response = await axios.get('http://localhost:1337/webinars')
      this.webinars = response.data
    } catch (error) {
      this.error = error;
    }
  },
  props: {
    header: String
  }
}
</script>
```

What I need to do is create a view that renders when you hit a webinar particular ID ('http://localhost:1337/webinars/1', 'http://localhost:1337/webinars/2' etc)

My understanding is I need to use [dynamic routes](https://next.router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/dynamic-routing.html#adding-routes-inside-navigation-guards). So I modified my router and added the import statement that pulls in the view, as well as adding the declaration:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import VueRouter from 'vue-router'
import Home from '../views/Home.vue'
import Webinars from '../views/Webinars.vue'
import WebinarSingle from '../views/WebinarSingle.vue'

Vue.use(VueRouter)

const routes = [
  {
    path: '/',
    name: 'Home',
    component: Home
  },
  {
    path: '/about',
    name: 'About',
    // route level code-splitting
    // this generates a separate chunk (about.[hash].js) for this route
    // which is lazy-loaded when the route is visited.
    component: () => import(/* webpackChunkName: "about" */ '../views/About.vue')
  },
  {
    path: '/webinars',
    name: 'Webinars',
    component: Webinars
  },
  {
    path: '/webinars/:id',
    name: 'Webinars',
    component: WebinarSingle
  }
]

const router = new VueRouter({
  mode: 'history',
  base: process.env.BASE_URL,
  routes
})

export default router
```

I *think* the next step here is to now add in `<router-link>` tags to hit that webinar based on ID. https://router.vuejs.org/api/

> is the component for enabling user navigation in a
> router-enabled app. The target location is specified with the to prop.
> It renders as an  tag with correct href by default, but can be
> configured with the tag prop. In addition, the link automatically gets
> an active CSS class when the target route is active.
>
> is preferred over hard-coded  for the
> following reasons:
>
> It works the same way in both HTML5 history mode and hash mode, so if
> you ever decide to switch mode, or when the router falls back to hash
> mode in IE9, nothing needs to be changed. In HTML5 history mode,
> router-link will intercept the click event so that the browser doesn't
> try to reload the page. When you are using the base option in HTML5
> history mode, you don't need to include it in to prop's URLs.

So I go ahead and attempt to add them into the webinars component:

```
<template>
    <div>
      <h1>{{ header }}</h1>
      <div v-if="error" class="webinar-error">
        <h1>{{ error }}</h1>
      </div>
      <div v-else>
        <div class="webinar-card" v-for="webinar in webinars" :key="webinar.id">
          <router-link to="/webinars/{{ webinar.id }}">
            <h3>{{ webinar.webinar_title }}</h3>
            <p>{{ webinar.webinar_description }}</p>
          </router-link>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
</template>
```

This returns:

> Module Error (from
> ./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/loaders/templateLoader.js): (Emitted
> value instead of an instance of Error)
>
> Errors compiling template:
>
> to="/webinars/{{ webinar.id }}": Interpolation inside attributes has
> been removed. Use v-bind or the colon shorthand instead. For example,
> instead of , use .

So I change it to:

```
<template>
    <div>
      <h1>{{ header }}</h1>
      <div v-if="error" class="webinar-error">
        <h1>{{ error }}</h1>
      </div>
      <div v-else>
        <div class="webinar-card" v-for="webinar in webinars" :key="webinar.id">
          <router-link :to="/webinars/{{ webinar.id }}">
            <h3>{{ webinar.webinar_title }}</h3>
            <p>{{ webinar.webinar_description }}</p>
          </router-link>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
</template>
```

I then get:

> error  in
> ./src/components/Webinars.vue?vue&type=template&id=44d01bf9&
>
> Syntax Error: Unexpected token (1:301)

What is the unexpected token?

How do you map dynamic routes in vue js to different endpoints?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the first error states, [interpolation](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/syntax.html#Interpolations) inside attributes is no longer supported. The interpolation being the `{{ }}` template syntax that you use. The docs explain [how to bind values in attributes](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/syntax.html#Attributes)

When you `v-bind` an attribute, the value you assign it is no longer treated like a normal string. So, when you write:

```js
<router-link :to="/webinars/{{ webinar.id }}">
```

The value assigned to `:to` is treated as javascript. `/webinars/{{webinar.id}}` being an invalid javascript expression.

There are a few ways to achieve what you want:

[ES6 Template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)

```js
<router-link :to="`/webinars/${webinar.id}`">
```

String concatenation

```js
<router-link :to="'/webinars/' + webinar.id">
```